# Rails: create a method to an object in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I've a table called **users** that has an association has_and_belongs_to_many with the table **departments**.
In the views/users/index.html.erb I want to display the departments that belongs to the users with a string Example: "Image, Direction". I already get this string form a user with the next code in my console:

```
> p1 = users.find(1)
> pd1 = p1.departments
> for dep in pd1 do
  * t=t + dep.name+", "
>end
>t=t[0..-3]
```

my views/users/index.html.erb is like:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= user.phone %></td>
    <td><%= user.birthday.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></td>
    <td><%= user.findDepartments %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
```

so I'm trying to use user.findDepartments to display the string. I defined the findDepartments method in the user controller:

```
def self.findDepartments
d=self.departments
for dep in d do
   t=t+dep.name+ ", "
end
t=t[0..-3]
end
```

And the error that I receive is:
**undefined method `findDepartments' for #**

---

**EDIT:** I've just realised how to do it. just erase the findDepartments method from the controller and put it into the user model with these modifications:

```
def findDepartments
    t=""
    d=self.departments
    puts d
    for dep in d do
       t=t+dep.name+ ", "
    end
    t=t[0..-3]
end
```

Comment: can you post the full error message?

Comment: You should define the findDepartments in the model and not in the controller

Comment: you created findDepartments as a class method, but you try to call it as an instance method on user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an instance method, but use next code:

```
 def deparments_names
   self.departments.limit(3).collect(&:name).join(", ")
 end
```

I don't know why you need to do [0..-3] but you can add this code after join(''). But I would say that you need also to check if there any departments.

Answer (score 1):

you have to define `findDepartments` as `instance method`

```
def findDepartments
  d=self.departments
  for dep in d do
    t=t+dep.name+ ", "
  end
  t=t[0..-3]
end
```